# How to get properties of a class in an array

Tags: c#

I have a student class with the following structure:

```
    public sealed class Student
    {
       public string Name {get;set;}
       public string RollNo {get;set;}
       public string standard {get;set;}
       public bool IsScholarshipped {get;set;}
       public List<string> MobNumber {get;set;}
    }
```

How can I get those properties of 
        Student
class in an array like

```
     arr[0]=Name;
     arr[1]=RollNo; 
      .
      .
      .
     arr[4]=MobNumber
```

And the types of these properties in separate array like

```
     arr2[0]=string;
     arr2[1]=string;
      .
      .
      .
     arr2[4]=List<string> or IEnumerable
```

Please , explain it with chunk of code.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? There may be a good reason but off the top of my head I can't think of anything good that will come of having this data in arrays...

Comment: Sounds like you should add the homework tag. The magic keyword to google for is *reflection*

Comment: Homework tag has been depricated.

Comment: `typeof(Student).GetProperties()` will return public properties for you, but I also don't understand why you need that

Comment: I want those properties in an array for making a tabular report.

Comment: You could use reflection to find all public instance properties. From there you could get the names and types of the properties. I'm not sure if the order matters? I.e. must `Name` be at index `0`, and `RollNo` at `1`, and so on? Also, do you want the identifyer, like `"Name"`, or do you want the actual value from some specific instance, like `"Peter Jones"`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var type = model.GetType();
var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

That will give you an array of `PropertyInfo`. You can then do this to get just the names:

```
properties.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
```

Comment: Hey, suggest something for the type of the properties too..Plz

Comment: Check out MSDN for the PropertyInfo object. `PropertyType` should do the trick! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx

Answer (score 6):

You can use reflection:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(Student).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
   '''
}
```

Comment: This way we only get the properties.I want them in an array.

Comment: This enumerates through properties. This is idea, I do not like to give complete solutions!

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ on the results of `GetProperty`, like this:

```
var props = typeof(Student).GetProperties();
var names = props
    .Select(p => p.Name)
    .ToArray();
var types = props
    .Select(p => p.PropertyType)
    .ToArray();
for (int i = 0 ; i != names.Length ; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", names[i], types[i]);
}
```

Here is what gets printed:

```
Name System.String
RollNo System.String
standard System.String
IsScholarshipped System.Boolean
MobNumber System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

Comment: I don't want the FullNames of the types just want the Names

Comment: Presumably, `GetProperties()` returns the members in the same order both times.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That's a 100% certainty, because `GetProeprties()` returns a copy of the same array.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm sure you're right. I checked the source for `System.RuntimeType`, the private method `GetPropertyCandidates`. It gets some list from a cache, then runs through it to check which items are appropriate, adding them to a `List<>`, and finally calls `.ToArray()` on this `List<>`. But it would still be better if your code called `GetProperties()` only once.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You're right, that's an easy change, and it also shortens the code.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use operator [] overloading for this purpose. The properties can be mapped using PropertyInfo.

```
public sealed class Student
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string RollNo { get; set; }
  public string Standard { get; set; }
  public bool IsScholarshipped { get; set; }
  public List<string> MobNumber { get; set; }

  public object this[int index]
  {
    get
    {
      // Note: This may cause IndexOutOfRangeException!
      var propertyInfo = this.GetType().GetProperties()[index];
      return propertyInfo != null ? propertyInfo.GetValue(this, null) : null;
    }
  }

  public object this[string key]
  {
    get
    {
      var propertyInfo = this.GetType().GetProperties().First(x => x.Name == key);
      return propertyInfo != null ? propertyInfo.GetValue(this, null) : null;
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use the class in this way:

```
var student = new Student { Name = "Doe, John", RollNo = "1", IsScholarshipped = false, MobNumber = new List<string>(new[] { "07011223344" }) };

var nameByIndex = student[0] as string;
var nameByKey = student["Name"] as string;
```

Read more about the [] Operator at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3hd7ste%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Note that accessing Properties by index this way is prone to error since the order of properties easily change without any control.

Comment: What if we add a new Field ? You should use reflection instead of your switch/case

Comment: Correct @hoang. I updated the example using PropertyInfo to mitigate the problem of adding or removing properties.

Comment: Still that is not really what the OP wants :p